# Layouting Dojo Mobile App

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo

`Hi,`
does anybody has any experience with layouting a dojo mobile application? I would like to have a header section in my app and on one page a sub navigation underneath the header followed by a scrollable content section and finally a main navigation at the bottom. Everything should be displayed at a time so that you don’t need to scroll to reach any navigation. Problem is that if I have everything visible, I am no longer able to see everything of the scrollable content section because the navigation is lying over it or if the scrollable content section is fully readable I have to scroll to reach every navigation. Does anybody has any idea how to accomplish that layout? Here is my code and also an example you can watch.

Example: [click here](http://www.ralfhecktor.de/dojo)

Code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <title>Layout</title>

                <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js.uncompressed.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                               // Use the lightweight parser
                               dojo.require("dojox.mobile.parser");
                               // Require Dojo mobile
                               dojo.require("dojox.mobile");
                               dojo.require("dojox.mobile.TabBar");
                               dojo.require("dojox.mobile.ScrollableView");
                               //Require the compat if the client isn't Webkit-based
                               dojo.requireIf(!dojo.isWebKit,"dojox.mobile.compat");

                               dojo.ready(function() {
                                               // Parse the page!
                                               dojox.mobile.parser.parse();
                               });

                </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.View" id="content-1" selected="true">

                               <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" id="heading-1">
                                               Heading 1
                               </div>                  

                               <ul dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBar" barType="segmentedControl" id="top-nav">
                                               <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" id="top-nav-1" moveTo="content-1-1" selected="true">Top-Nav 1</li>
                                               <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" id="top-nav-2" moveTo="content-1-2">Top-Nav 2</li>
                                               <li dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" id="top-nav-3" moveTo="content-1-3">Top-Nav 3</li>
                               </ul>

                               <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="content-1-1" selected="true">

                                               <h3>Content 1-1</h3>

                                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                                               Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                                               natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                                               ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                                               eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec
                                               pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
                                               In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
                                               Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
                                               Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
                                               eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
                                               eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
                                               feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
                                               Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
                                               Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. 
                                               Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper 
                                               libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit 
                                               vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
                                               ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
                                               Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
                                               Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis
                                               magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun. 
                               </div>

                               <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="content-1-2">

                                               <h3>Content 1-2</h3>

                                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                                               Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                                               natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                                               ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                                               eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec
                                               pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
                                               In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
                                               Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
                                               Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
                                               eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
                                               eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
                                               feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
                                               Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
                                               Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. 
                                               Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper 
                                               libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit 
                                               vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
                                               ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
                                               Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
                                               Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis
                                               magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun. 
                               </div>

                               <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="content-1-3">

                                               <h3>Content 1-3</h3>

                                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                                               Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                                               natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                                               ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                                               eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec
                                               pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
                                               In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
                                               Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
                                               Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
                                               eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
                                               eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
                                               feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
                                               Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
                                               Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. 
                                               Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper 
                                               libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit 
                                               vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
                                               ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
                                               Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
                                               Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis
                                               magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun. 
                               </div>

                </div>

                <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="content-2">

                               <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" id="heading-2" fixed="top">
                                               Heading 2
                               </div>                  

                               <h3>Content 2-1</h3>

                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                               Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                               natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                               ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                               u, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec
                               pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
                               In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
                               Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
                               Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
                               eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
                               eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
                               feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
                               Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
                               Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. 
                               Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper 
                               libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit 
                               vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
                               ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
                               Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
                               Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis
                               magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun. 

                </div>

                <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView" id="content-3">

                               <div dojoType="dojox.mobile.Heading" id="heading-3" fixed="top">
                                               Heading 3
                               </div>                  

                               <h3>Content 3-1</h3>

                               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
                               Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis 
                               natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                               ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
                               eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec
                               pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
                               In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.
                               Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
                               Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate 
                               eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, 
                               eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis,
                               feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet.
                               Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
                               Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. 
                               Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper 
                               libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit 
                               vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et
                               ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus.
                               Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
                               Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis
                               magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun. 

                </div>

                <ul id="bottom-nav" dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBar">
                               <li id="bottom-nav-1" dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" selected="true" moveTo="content-1">Content 1</li>
                               <li id="bottom-nav-2" dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" moveTo="content-2">Content 2</li>
                               <li id="bottom-nav-3" dojoType="dojox.mobile.TabBarButton" moveTo="content-3">Content 3</li>
                </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: To be a bit more precise I made some images which you can find [here](http://www.ralfhecktor.de/dojo/images.htm)

I hope these images help to understand what I would like to achive. I would like to have an app layout which has a header, underneath that a sub navigation followed by a content area which is scrollable and finally a footer with the main navigation. Everything should be visible at a time!!! So the content area shoul get the height of the display - header - footer - subNav.

```
|-------------------------------|
|           Header              |
|-------------------------------|
|        Sub navigation         |
|-------------------------------|
|                               |
|     Scrollable content        |
|                               |
|    Height = display-height -  |
|    header - subNav - footer   |
|                               |
|-------------------------------|
|    Footer / Main navigation   |
|-------------------------------|
```

I hope a layout like this is possible with Dojo mobile.

Thanks for your support!!!
Ralf

Comment: Be a bit more detailed in what you want to achieve.  Draw a picture perhaps.  It seems obvious that if you header + content + footer (what you call the navigation section) is longer than the height of the screen, then one of the, must be scrolled and you can't show everything.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I added some more details and also images. Hope it helps to understand my endeavour and somebody can help me :-)

Comment: This is a very simple/standard mobile layout, which can be done very quickly with CSS.  Which part is giving you the prob?

Comment: The problem is, that Dojo Mobile seems to assign every div having the dojoType of View or ScrollableView a height which is the height of the viewport. I was wondering whether there are some other attributes  I can use to tell dojo to assign that div a dynamic height without doing some own javascript. Because as you said, it is a very simple and basic mobile layout and I can not imagine that it is not possible without using additional javascript. Css by the way won't work because the height is set by the framework via javascript during runtime.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you'll have to override dojox.mobile's standard CSS styles for this.  I do it all the time for my own projects -- having a fixed header and footer that are separate from the views in the middle.

Comment: Ok, so let me ask one (maybe dumb) question. What are the advantages of dojox.mobile instead of just using dojo in a normal manner and style it for mobile devices? That's not quite clear to me.

Comment: 1) Other Dojo widgets (i.e. dijit's) are too heavy weight -- i.e. too much code -- to download, 2) digits don't always run on a touch-screen (pre 1.6), 3) dijit's assume a mouse-and-keyboard paradigm, not touch, so you don't have the nice sliding effects etc. (pre-1.7).  dojox.mobile is much lighter weight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.  Just make use of `fixed="top"` and `fixed="bottom"`.

Since you already have the footer outside of the ScrollableView, just add `fixed="bottom"`.  According to the docs, you need `fixed="top"` on the two heading elements, but it seems to work fine without those.

More info here (in particular, see examples at bottom of page): http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/mobile/ScrollableView.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The Problem with fixed="top" and fixed="bottom" in this case is, that there is still the sub navigation underneath the header which needs space. I didn't figure out any constellation in which the content was fully scrollable/readable without having something lying over if everything is on the screen at a time or if the content is fully scrollable/readable, something of the navigation in the footer or part of the header is out of the actual viewport. Any idea how to handle this? Without the sub navigation, thats the way to do it! But what about with? Thanks!

Comment: I added `fixed="top"` to both header `heading-1` and tabbar `top-nav`. Running in Safari with user agent set to iPhone Safari and it works correctly for me.

Comment: Yeah, except the fact, that top-nav is in front of heading-1 so that you only can see top-nav but no longer heading-1. That is the only problem I need to get rid of :-) [click here for an example](http://www.ralfhecktor.de/dojo/index2.htm)

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I'm using Dojo 1.7b2.  The mobile widgets have received a sizable update in Dojo 1.7.  What you are seeing is a bug that seems to have been fixed in 1.7.

Comment: Oh ok, interessting :-) 1.7b2 is working for you? The last time I tried it it just destroyed my whole layout :D Do you maybe know when the final/stable version of 1.7 is released? Thanks :)

Comment: I just checked out the trunk an tried it with 1.7 and it really worked :-) I have one last question for you Javier. I do have a little problem with the tabbar in my footer when displaying the page with any webkit browser. Although I added the attribute `fixed="bottom"` the tabbar is about 100px above the bottom of the viewport. Did you have the same issue and if so how did you fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I saw that as well.  Seems to be a bug/quirk in the Dojo code.  If you inspect the HTML/CSS, you see that the TabBar has a class of `mblTabBarNoIcons`, which sets the height shorter than necessary, causing the extra space at the bottom. If I manually remove that class in the Inspector, then the TabBar correctly takes up all the space at the bottom of the page.  Maybe open a bug on Dojo?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that doesn't solve it for me. `mblTabBarNoIcon` is only assigned to the `ul` when there are no icons used. As I will use icon the class won't be assigned anyway. It looks like the body or html gets a wrong height maybe also the view. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  You might need to open a bug on Dojo about this issue.